# Patterns match is not working properly for matches() method

Tags: java, regex

I have this text from file which I would like to get values using pattern match:

```
<!--
    @author: batman
    @description: 100000
-->
```

I'm using this code to find comments into XML files and get values using Patterns match:

```
XMLStreamReader xr = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file));

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("@(?<key>([\\w]+)?): (?<value>(.+)?)");
while (xr.hasNext())
{
    if (xr.next() == XMLStreamConstants.COMMENT) {
        String comment = xr.getText();
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(comment);

        if(!matcher.matches()){
            continue;
        }
.....
}
```

When I run the code I get error:

```
persistence-configuration.xsd (No such file or directory)
  at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [4,69]
```

But when I remove `matcher.matches()` I get several iterations if `xr` because I have several comments into XML file.

The idea is to get only the comment with the proper match and to skip the rest of the comments. Do you know why the code is not working fine?

I tried also with `"@(?<key>[\\w]+): (?<value>.*)"` but again I get the same issue.

Comment: Could you post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: Did you try `if(!matcher.find()){`? Please don't enclose single shorthands in brackets, it is fraught with unexpected behavior, `[\\w]+` => `\\w+`

Comment: I just tried both cases but it's not working. I get the same error: `persistence-configuration.xsd (No such file or directory)`

Comment: I think, we can be very sure that the `No such file or directory` error does *not* stem from the regex engine.

Answer (score 0):

Is you input source actually there? The exception you get hints at a file problem.

`Matcher.matches()` tests a `String` for complete confirmity with the entire pattern. All characters of the input sequence need to be consumed. So if your line starts with blanks (tabs, whitespaces...) then your matcher may fail to match, if you use `matches`.

You are looking for `matcher.find()`, which can be used like this:

```java
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("somePattern");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("someInput");
while (matcher.find()) {
    // this is where you can check what you found...
}
```

Besides, you may want to check, at what chunks the stream provides elements. Are they really coming linewise?

Comment: Yes, in some files I might have blank starting lines. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Yes. Use `find()` instead of `matches()`.

Comment: You have multiple overlapping problems. The regex is only one problem, but you also cannot access the file. Either because it is missing, or because you have no permission to access it.

Comment: How I can fix the regex?

Comment: Your regex is not the primary problem! Your primary problem is that you are trying to read something that is not there. `String comment = xr.getText();` `<-` check if this causes the problem. Most of all: Find out what line is actually throwing the error.